# Retrieve current host from within an executed task

Tags: python, fabric

I'm using fabric to execute some remote commands on several hosts by setting:

```
env.hosts = [host1, host2, ...]
```

There are several tasks I want to perform on some of the hosts, and some I don't.
is there's a way I can retrieve the current hostname the task is executing on?

Any help would be great.
Thanks,
Meny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use different host roles?

```
from fabric.api import env, roles, run

env.roledefs['webservers'] = ['www1', 'www2', 'www3']

@roles('webservers')
def my_task():
    run('ls -l')
```

Additionally, you can get the current executing host from the `env` dictionary:

```
def my_task():
    print 'Currently executing on {0}'.format(env.host)
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. thanks!
One question though.
If I got a task that i need to run on both set of roles, should i keep env.hosts with all the servers in it and not add a decorator?

Comment: One last thing.
It appears I have a task that still needs to be aware of the current host it's performing on.
For example, one of my tasks uploads some files to Amazon S3.
Each host should append it's name to the upload path.
Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: Updated my answer for getting the host's name.

Comment: Just found it out myself also, but you were here first :)

Answer (score 1):

eclaird answer definitely helped me use a better practice when executing tasks on several hosts with different roles.

Though, while playing with it, it seems that within the task, env.host will give the name of the current hostname.
for example:

```
@parallel(pool_size=len(env.hosts))
def upload_to_s3(to):
    awscreds = 'some credentials...'
    cmd = '%s aws s3 sync /mnt/backup %s/%s/' % (awscreds, to, env.host)
    run(cmd)
```